# DRF Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to return the details of the current logged in user in the following way:

```
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserDetailsView(RetrieveAPIView):                                                                                                                                                                           
    model = User                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    queryset = User.objects.all()                                                                                                                                                                                 
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]                                                                                                                                                            
    serializer_class = UserSerializer                                                                                                                                                                             

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                      
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)                                                                                                                                                               
        print(user)                                                                                                                                                                                               
        return Response(user)
```

in serializers.py I've use `ModelSerializer`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                                                                                                                                
      password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)                                                                                                                                                             

      def create(self, validated_data):                                                                                                                                                                             
          user = UserModel.objects.create(username=validated_data['username'])                                                                                                                                      
          user.set_password(validated_data['password'])                                                                                                                                                             
          user.save()                                                                                                                                                                                               
          return user                                                                                                                                                                                               

      class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          model = UserModel                                                                                                                                                                                         
          fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')                                                                                                                                                                   
          write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

I get an error `Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable`. What is wrong in my use case?

Answer (score 8):

You need to return

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

in your get function under UserDetailsView. More details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/).

Comment: This solved my problem. It would be nice to get the snippet onto your answer so beginners don't go looking through the entire page and not knowing where to look.

Answer (score 6):

DRF response should be JSON-like objects, to convert model instanse to it you use seralizer class:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                      
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)    
    serializer = self.get_serializer(user)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also you dont need additional query to get current user, you can user `request.user` directly:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(request.user)    
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check you are returning value of particular field  in serializer get method, not entire user object.